# How to add new column containing letters from an existing column (tidyr)

Tags: r, dataset, tidyr

I have a data like this:

[image: Data I currently have]

The letters in the `value` column are notes describing the value.

I need to create an additional column containing only the letters from the value column and the number and the ":" will retain their position.

I know that I need to use regular expression, for example. //w and that would do it.

Is there an easy way how to do it for example in tidyr?

Thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate(value, into = c('number', 'letter'), sep = ' ')
```